# Extract a number from string in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract a number form a string like this in Python:

```
string1 = 154787xs.txt
```

I want to get `154787` from there. I am using this:

```
searchPattern = re.compile('\d\d\d\d\d\d(?=xs)')
m = searchPattern.search(string1)
number = m.group()
```

but I do not get the correct value. Also the number of digits could change...

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: I *do* get the correct value; `number == '154787'`. Could you be clearer about what you think the problem is? Also, you can specify a number of repeats for a character with e.g. `\d{6}` (exactly six) or `\d{4, 8}` (between four and eight).

Answer (score 2):

Simply you could use the below pattern,

```
searchPattern = re.compile(r'\d+(?=xs)')
```

**Explanation:**

- `\d+` matches one or more numbers.
- `(?=xs)` Lookahead asserts that the characters which are following the numbers must be `xs`

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> searchPattern = re.compile(r'\d+(?=xs)')
>>> m = searchPattern.search(string1)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f6047f66370>
>>> number = m.group()
>>> number
'154787'
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when you say you do not get the right value?
Your code does successfully match the *string* `'154787'`.
Perhaps you want `number` to be an `int`? In that case use:

```
number = int(m.group())
```

---

By the way, the regex could be written as

```
searchPattern = re.compile('(\d+)xs')
m = searchPattern.search(string1)
if m:
    number = int(m.group(1))
```